# Auto-Filter Method Failing - Run-Time Error 1004

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

How are you doing?

Here's my question. I'm trying to apply an autofilter which the criterias are Dates that depends on which Quarter of the year we are. Here's the code.

```
If fator = 1 Then
    DataInicio = DateSerial(Year(Date), 10, 1)
    DataFinal = DateSerial(Year(Date), 12, 31)
ElseIf fator = 2 Then
    DataInicio = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)
    DataFinal = DateSerial(Year(Date), 3, 31)
ElseIf fator = 3 Then
    DataInicio = DateSerial(Year(Date), 4, 1)
    DataFinal = DateSerial(Year(Date), 6, 30)
ElseIf fator = 4 Then
    DataInicio = DateSerial(Year(Date), 7, 1)
    DataFinal = DateSerial(Year(Date), 9, 30)
End If

wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").Activate

If wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").AutoFilterMode = True And wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").FilterMode = True Then
    wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").ShowAllData
ElseIf wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").AutoFilterMode = False Then
    wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter
End If

wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").Range("A:P").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">="& DataInicio, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:="<=" & DataFinal
```

I tried to use Criteria1 and Criteria2, both Criteria1, both Criteria2 and didn't work. Could someone give me a hand here?

Thanks again for the support! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Autofilter can be picky about date formats. Try converting to a Double first:

```
wb.Sheets("Change-Order FUP").Range("A:P").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">="& CDbl(DataInicio), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(DataFinal)
```

Comment: Hi Rory! Thanks for your reply. This change couldn't make it either. The error remains the same (1004). I'll try changing the variable i'm using for filtering. If it works, i'll reply here! Thanks again.

Comment: @MaurícioCésarBrichesi There was a typo in the code (repeated Criteria1 instead of Criteria2) which I have now fixed - please retest.

Comment: Couldn't make either! The same run-time error. Thanks again for replying.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?